# set Different drawables to Group and Child list when clicked

Tags: android, xml, drawable, expandablelistview

I am searching around about expandable list view in android.
so, we know that there's group-list and child-list...
I want to ask if it's possible, if I want a different drawables
between group and child list, when they're clicked...

e.g.the group will be red and child will be blue when clicked.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the drawable for an item that is pressed using [state list drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). But the state of group item should not be changed automatically when the child item state is changed. So it's your task to change the group item state.

But be careful solving this task. List items are rendered by a list adapter and that rendering must be based on the state of items inside the adapter. So, in child items click listener you should change the state of an appropriate group object (something like group.pressed=true, where 'pressed' is a member of your group class) and call [adapter.notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29). And in [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method of the adapter you should analyze that property and configure the group item drawable.